# Node midi I/O module has a slight latency

Tags: node.js, midi

I have a small script in nodejs that utilizes the `midi` module, and the whole thing works without a hitch, except that there's a small, about 50ms delay from the input to output. The script looks like this:

```
var midi = require('midi');
var output = new midi.output();
output.getPortCount();
output.getPortName(0);
output.openPort(0);
var input = new midi.input();
input.getPortCount();
input.getPortName(0);
input.on('message', function(deltaTime, message) {
    output.sendMessage(message);
});
input.openPort(0);
input.ignoreTypes(false, false, false);
```

Any ideas on why this latency is present?

Comment: Because it's JavaScript and probably not the greatest tool for extremely low-latency I/O (or at the very least, I wouldn't bank on its event mechanism)? Plus npm packages aren't exactly renowned for quality control.

Comment: I figured as much.

Comment: You could give Python a shot, its architecture is significantly different (and even if you don't know Python it's relatively easy to learn and yields rapid development comparable to Node in many cases). I've never done any MIDI stuff in Python but at a glance https://github.com/patrickkidd/pyrtmidi looks promising (and there are others). This advice, of course, assumes there isn't an actual solution to your Node problem.

Comment: JavaScript isn't necessarily a problem, but there may be delays depending on how the events are set up.  In any case, I don't get latency much lower than that on any software, even purpose-built software with very good MIDI implementations such as Ableton Live.  MIDI I/O on a computer is not what you want to use for MIDI routing.  Use some off-the-shelf MIDI routing hardware for that, which runs in realtime.